# Add Media with Spatie/laravel-medialibrary without related to model (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, media-library

I am using latest version (10.15) of [Spatie/laravel-medialibrary](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary).

It is very simple to upload media rlated to a model, look like this:

```php
$model->addMediaFromRequest('file');
```

or in other ways.

But, now I want to put some files without related to any model instance.

As mentioned in this issue https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary/pull/1443, but it isn't merged because of some problems,

It is okay to use other strategies like put in storage without using this package, but it is good to know if there is any way to do my desire.

Anyhow, if you know how I resolve this problem I appreciate you to increase developers' society knowledge.

Thanks